# GDB Print Value Relative to Register

Tags: c, memory, assembly, x86, gdb

Ok, so basically I'm wondering how to print the value of a memory address that is at an offset from the address stored in a register in GDB. For instance, take this assembly line:

```
mov 0x34(%esp),%edx
```

In my understanding, this takes the value 52 bytes after the address pointed to by the stack pointer, and stores that value inside of the edx register. In this case the value is a string, so it would be storing a char *. When using the examine command inside of GDB on the edx register:

```
x/s $edx
```

It prints out the string as it's supposed to. However, when I try to print out the string by directly examining the location it was copied from using this command:

```
x/s $esp + 0x34
```

It prints out garbage. Why is this? Have I misunderstood the syntax of the GDB command, or is it something else?

Comment: what's the length of your string/

Answer (score 11):

`x` command print out the data at address pointed to by register specified. For example `x/s $edx` prints string starting at address defined by the value of `edx` register. It should also print the address itself.

Let's assume the value of `esp` is `0x7fffff00` and value loaded from `0x34(%esp)` to `edx` is `0x43210`.
`x/s $edx` will print string at location `0x43210` in a manner similar to this:

```
(gdb) x/s $esp
0x0x43210:   "hello world!"
```

While `x/s $esp + 0x34` will actually try to print a string starting at `0x7fffff34`. There is pointer to actual string there, so if you do `x/wx $esp + 0x34` you should see the pointer to your string (`0x43210`). The "garbage" you see is this pointer (and following data) represented as string.

Answer (score 1):

```
x/s *(void**)($esp + 0x34)
```

works

Comment: Or, just `p *(char**)($esp + 0x34)`